# For Each 10 Ads - 2 Banner Loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, each

http://prntscr.com/nwt8ir

Yellow section in image is ads.
Red section in image is banner.

I want to do as in the picture with the for each cycle.

My Codes:

```
$adss = $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $adss->rowCount() )
{
foreach( $adss as $ads ){ ?>
<img src="$ads['image']">
<?php } } ?>

$banners= $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY id DESC" PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( $banners->rowCount() )
{
foreach( $banners $banner){ ?>
<img src="$banner['image']">
<?php } } ?>
```

There will be 10 ads in the loop. Then there will be 2 banners. I'm waiting for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to run both those foreach loops forever? You could put both loops inside a never-ending while loop, with the queries outside the loop for less server work:

```
$adss = $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY id DESC", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$banners= $baglan->query("SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY id DESC" 
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($adss->rowCount() && $banners->rowCount()){
    while(true){
      foreach( $adss as $ads ){ ?>
         <img src="$ads['image']">
      <?php } ?>
    foreach( $banners $banner){ ?>
         <img src="$banner['image']">
      <?php }
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to return 2 banners after 10 ads. That's exactly what I want. http://prntscr.com/nwt8ir